# Instantly update created record with a WITH clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to update a record, created with `WITH` clause in the same query, like so:

```
WITH
  document AS (
    INSERT INTO documents (name) VALUES ($1)
    RETURNING *
  )
UPDATE documents
SET documents.description = $2
FROM document
WHERE documents.id = document.id;
```

I've also tried

```
WITH
  new_document AS (
    INSERT INTO documents (name) VALUES ($1)
    RETURNING *
  ),
  updated_document AS (
    UPDATE documents
    SET documents.description = $2
    WHERE documents.id = (SELECT id FROM new_document)
    RETURNING *
  )
SELECT * FROM updated_document;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I know this example is silly since I can simply create a new document with both name and description at the same time, but I need it to do it this way in my app; the example is simplified on purpose.

### Edit

I've created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/egorovli/effd6d1dcdf2a92e34cdee3512c50528) with a real world example. I know I can embed the logic of updating `document_id` into the function body. I guess. But imagine that `urls` can correspond not only to documents, but to many other entities, like, documents, stories, users, articles, tags, etc., etc., embedding references to all these entities into the function body is tedious, since (due to function overloading) I would have to create functions like `get_url_for_document(id uuid)`, `get_url_for_story(id uuid)`, `get_url_for_user(id uuid)`, etc., etc.

Answer (score 2):

Do it in two separate statements or inside a function. You cannot do it like you tried due to the way how WITH is implemented.

From [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other
>   and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
>   statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually
>   happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same
>   snapshot (see Chapter 13), so they cannot "see" one another's effects
>   on the target tables.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll have to come up with a less awkward approach 

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting to do is impossible.

From the manual:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

```
WITH t AS (
    UPDATE products SET price = price * 1.05
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM products;
```

the outer SELECT would return the original prices before the action of the UPDATE, while in

```
WITH t AS (
    UPDATE products SET price = price * 1.05
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM t;
```

the outer SELECT would return the updated data.

---

In your given example your update trying to act on rows which don't exist.  This is not fixable using a WITH clause.

I would be interested to understand why your code has forced you to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. In case you're curious, I've updated my question with a link to a gist, showing the use case.